# What does taking Raw value for EV3 Colour sensor do?

Tags: ev3, sensor-colour

I participate in Robotics competitions like the WRO and I want to know if using EV3 colour sensor raw values helps in line follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you take a Raw value from any sensor, the EV3 brick passes on the reading as reported directly from the sensor, without doing any processing. Especially for the color sensor, where you have several modes such as Reflection and Color Number, the EV3 brain does do post-processing on the input value to make the output easier to understand and/or use. By getting the raw value you are likely get a higher resolution signal than in any of the other modes, at the expense of potential error correction.

Comment: As for the range? What values does it give,  from 0-100 or is it 0-255 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It will from 1 to 255. Now I try to measure color via RGB value to make the rank higher than using color sensor value block.